# Diagnosing USB Power bank shut-off on load application

Tags: audio, bluetooth, usb-c, powerbanks

I'm trying to create a small bluetooth boombox-style speaker, but am having trouble powering the device from a USB battery bank.

Fundamental Problem: The power bank "shuts off" as soon as the load is connected.

The [Bluetooth Amplifier Board](https://www.parts-express.com/dayton-audio-kab-215-2x15w-class-d-audio-amplifier-board-with-bluetooth-21--325-100) wants 12V input, so I'm using a [ZDP12N](https://www.ebay.com/itm/ZY12PDN-Type-C-PD-to-DC-USB-SurfacePro-Decoy-Fast-Charge-Trigger-Poller-/132745937609) on the USB-C output of the [USB-C Power Bank](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07N3RGNY6). I have confirmed that I get 12V output on the terminals of the ZDP12N with no load applied.

When I connect the amplifier board to the power bank (through the ZDP12N), the battery bank immediately shuts off. Thus began the troubleshooting. Here are some things I tried and the results I got:

1. Power the bluetooth board off of 12V from a power supply.

   - Result: Board works as intended. Pulls 50 mA at 12V = 600mW, so load is definitely not too big for the power bank which can output 1.5A @ 12V
2. Power the board through the ZDP12N with a USB-C laptop charger instead of the battery bank

   - Result: Board works as intended, no problems. I don't have a way to measure current here, but it doesn't seem to be any issue
3. Charge phone off of power bank

   - Result: Phone fast charges no problem

So basically I'm not sure what the best approach is here. I'm speculating that the load is too small and the device thinks it's connected to something malfunctioning and protecting itself. Either that or there is some large inrush for a very short period that is causing the device to shut off. I don't have an oscilloscope, so I can't visualize the startup current draw.

Thanks in advance for your advice on next steps.

P.S. [I've made a second post about why the speaker power draw seems too low](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/476801/lower-than-expected-power-consumption-from-speaker-drivers)

Comment: What kind of capacitance is on the input to your circuit

Comment: Hi @MadHatter, Unfortunately I'm not sure how to measure that. The research I did on measuring input capacitance didn't get me very far either. The amplifier has minimal documentation, as does the power bank. If you can provide guidance I'm happy to go measure